# Transfer null sql query result to a string

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm writing a query to get gross profit percentage "GP%" of a certain product to put it in a C# grid view by product by year. I Want the query result to be dynamic that in some years this product was n't sold so the result will be (profit/sales)=(0/0) it will be null. this null isn't accepted by C#.

The query is

```
SELECT
    FORMAT((SELECT ((ISNULL(SUM([Profit]), NULL)) / ISNULL(SUM([Sales]), NULL)) 
            FROM [dbo].[Sales] 
            WHERE [ProdHeir01_2] = 'Batteries' 
              AND [Sales_Year] = 2015 
              AND [Month_Number] BETWEEN 1 AND 8, 'P') AS [Percentage]
```

This query results in 'Null'. How can I insert a condition to transfer null to a string value. so the query to be dynamic :).

Thanks a lot in advance......

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is on technique you may find helpful:

select 0 / CASE WHEN IsNull([Sales],0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE [Sales] END

Comment: Thanks, but where can I write the selection and the mathematical equation

Answer (score 0):

Hady, here you go.

```
--CTE(Common Table Expression) with your query
WITH preselect AS
(
SELECT
    FORMAT(
            (SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Profit]), NULL) / ISNULL(SUM([Sales]), NULL)
                FROM [dbo].[Sales] 
                WHERE [ProdHeir01_2] = 'Batteries' 
                AND [Sales_Year] = 2015 
                AND [Month_Number] BETWEEN 1 AND 8
            )
              ,'P'
           ) AS [Percentage])

--Case statement that will return Null as string when Null and the percentage
--when it isn't null
SELECT CASE WHEN [Percentage] IS NULL THEN 'Null' ELSE [Percentage] END AS [Percentage]
FROM preselect
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, This answered the question. So grateful.